# Elastic search : query to get all elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't get all the items, the maximum reached is size:10000.
thanks

> Error: [query_phase_execution_exception] Result window is too large,
>   from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [90000].
>   See the scroll API for a more efficient way to request large data
>   sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window]
>   index level parameter.

Any idea how can I solve it?

```
GetTweets: function (callback) {
        client.search({
            index: 'twitter',
            type: 'tweet',
            size:10000,
            body: {
                query: {
                    "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }, function (err, resp, status) {
            callback(err,resp);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default feature of Elasticsearch not to get data at once after **10000** window ie. `size:10000` or upper. See here at [scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html), because of that restriction you're getting below error.

> Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000]

Try **Scroll API** like,

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?scroll=1m' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
'
```

The result from the above request includes a `_scroll_id`, which should be passed to the scroll API in order to retrieve the **next** batch of results.

```
curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_search/scroll'  -d'
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs2OzM0NDg1ODpzRlBLc0FXNlNyNm5JWUc1" 
}
'
```

**N.B** I've used both the `python` and `php` version of elasticsearch client api. Scroll API is really awesome and very flexible to get data-sets using it.

Answer (score 1):

`search_after` can be used to apply pagination.Efficient than Scroll Api

```
GET twitter/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    },
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
    "sort": [
        {"date": "asc"},
        {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
    ]
 }
```

ES docs: 
      `It is very similar to the scroll API but unlike it, the search_after parameter is stateless, it is always resolved against the latest version of the searcher`